# jQuery cannot catch the DataTable button class in Laravel

Tags: datatables, jquery-on, yajra-datatable

The button in td is from the DataTable Ajax back data:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default downpraise " data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" title="downbutton" name="downtest">
      <i class="far fa-thumbs-down">data</i>
</button>
```

My funtion is:

```
$('button[name="downtest"]').on('click',function(){
    console.log("downbutton push1);
})
```

or

```
$(".downpraise").on('click', function() {
    console.log("downbutton push2);
})
```

The above two do not get any responses? Any clues?

**PS:**

```
columns: [
          { data: 'action',  render: function ( data ) {              

        return  '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default downpraise " data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" title="downbutton" name="downtest">
             <i class="far fa-thumbs-down">data</i>
       </button>'
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the question by

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'button.downpraise', function () {
}
```

I don't know why the original method cannot work.